# Updating context data in FormView form_valid method?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a class `QuestionView` which is derived from the `FormView` class. Here
is a code snippet to explain my problem:

```
class QuestionView(FormView):
    ...
    context_var1 = y

    def form_valid (self, form):
        ...
        self.context_var1 = x
        ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        context['context_var1'] = self.context_var1
        ...
        return context
```

As shown above, I update a set of context variables in `form_valid` and
I intend to use the updated values of these in the template - hence the variables in the `context` dictionary. The problem with this code is that the change in
`context_var1` isn't seen - might be because `get_context_data` is
called before the `form_valid` method. Is there is a workaround for
this?

Answer (score 26):

I do this with `form_invalid`.  Here's how I do it:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class ContextFormView(FormView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

You could do the same but for form_valid.  Normally the body of form_valid looks like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

You would have to override both `post` and `form_valid`, because `post` calls `form_valid`.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form, **kwargs)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    # take some other action here
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

oh and just to clarify, the reason this problem exists is that the `ProcessFormView` class's `get` method is broken.  It normally looks like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

It just throws the kwargs away `(._.)`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Two years later and Django still doesn't provide a way to update context in form_valid or form_invalid.

Comment: And neither in django 1.7 :(

Comment: Do Django 1.8 provide a way to update context in form_valid?

Comment: The correct way to add to the context in `form_valid` is to use the `extra_context` attribute in Django 2.0 and newer. Just remember to override it by directly assigning a dictionary to it rather than doing a key assignment because its initial value is `None`.

Answer (score 5):

In views.py

```
class UploadTest(FormView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    ....
    plus_context = dict()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        self.plus_context['you_want_context'] = value
        ...
        return super(UploadTest, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UploadTest, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['plus_context_key'] = self.plus_context
        return context
```

In test.html

```
<html>
    ....
    <body>
    ....
    // first post can not get plus_context_key
    {% if plus_context_key %}
        {{ plus_context_key.you_want_context }}
    {% endif %}    
    </body>
</html>
```

I just figure out this way in Django 1.10.3.
Hope can help you

Comment: In case the form redirects to itself, this would display the `plus_context_key` contents even with a `GET` on the form view. To get around this, use `self.plus_context=dict()` after `context['plus_context_key']=self.plus_context` to reset the result for any later `GET`

Answer (score 5):

In Django 2.0.1 you can insert context data by overriding either `get_context_data` or `form_invalid`.

In your case you could do one of the following overrides:

```
class QuestionView(FormView):
    ...

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form, 
                context_key=some_value
            )
        )
```

Or:

```
class QuestionView(FormView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if 'context_key' not in kwargs:  # set value if not present
            kwargs['context_key'] = some_value
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Django 2.0.1 inserts under the hood the form into the kwargs of `get_context_data`.

```
# File: django.views.generic.edit

class FormMixin(ContextMixin):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Insert the form into the context dict."""
        if 'form' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this approach:

```
class SomeView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        my_form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            context['foo'] = 'bar'

        return render(request, 'valid/path.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass plus_context just if save successfull:

```
class SomeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('SomeUpdateView')
    plus_context = dict()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.plus_context:
            context['success'] = self.plus_context['pass_to_view_just_after_save_successful']
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        self.object.save()
        self.plus_context['pass_to_view_just_after_save_successful'] = 'Save successful!'
        return super(SomeUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

in template something like:

```
{% if success %}
<p>{{ success }}</p>
{% endif %}
```