# Django form content lost when redirecting using login_required

Tags: django, forms, post, get, login-required

I have problem similar to this one: [Django form data lost on making login required on post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272631/django-form-data-lost-on-making-login-required-on-post)
I want answer to be added if user is logged in otherwise redirect user to login page, let him login and then add his answer. My problem is that I lose content of the form when redirecting to login page.

These are my views:

```
def question(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    form = AnswerForm()

    return render(request, 'questions/question.html', {'question': question, 'form' : form},)

@login_required
def answer(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    form = AnswerForm(request.POST) if request.method == 'POST' else AnswerForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        answer = form.save(commit=False)
        answer.author = request.user
        answer.question = question
        answer.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('question', args=(question.id,)))
```

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'answer' question.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Odpowiedz">
</form>
```

Form in login template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{request.GET.next}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

I don't know if something more than url can be passed by using next.

Comment: Did you configure `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/your-app-home-url/'`

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to redirect to the home page

Answer (score 2):

`@login_required` decorator automatically adds a `next` GET parameter to the LOGIN_URL, so that user is redirected back to the same page the login was triggered from. Right now, you're triggering it from the `answer` view, so user will come back directly to answer view. POST Data is lost whenever a redirect occurs, so there's no way you can get the data except for temporarily saving it in cookies or redirecting the user to question page after login.

#### Implementation 1

POST Data is not saved but the user gets redirected to QuestionView

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
...
...

def answer(request, question_id):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("%s?next=%s" % (settings.LOGIN_URL, reverse('question-view-name'))
    ... 
    ...
```

#### Implementation 2

POST Data is saved to the session and then retrieved after login. I haven't tried it and it required you to serialize POST data to string. Also, requires `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE`. Checkout https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-sessions/ for how to set, create and delete session variables.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
...
...

def answer(request, question_id):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        request.session['form_data'] = YourSerializerFunctionToSerializeFormData(request.POST) 
        # must retuern a string, use json.dumps() to convert a dictionary to string

        return redirect("%s?next=%s" % (settings.LOGIN_URL, reverse('answer-view-name', args=[question_id]))

    data = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'form_data' in request.session:
            data = request.session['form_data']
            del request.session['form_data'] # Delete the key once done
    else:
        data = request.POST

    ...
    form = AnswerForm(data) if data else AnswerForm()
    ... 
    ...
```

Hope it helps.