# How to get POST parameters in a Django view protected by @login_required?

Tags: django, login-required

[Django's login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) requires a login before proceeding to any functionality in a view function.  If a user is not logged in, they will be redirected through a login screen.

If the HTTP request is a GET, Django sometimes puts the GET destination in a parameter ("next").  Or, Django also has a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting that is a URL a user is forwarded to after login.

If the HTTP request is a POST, that POST data is lost during the login process.

What is the best way to preserve the original URL and POST data for the original POST request, and re-post that data after the user is logged in?

I imagine putting something in a session, but I'd have to intercept the POST data and URL on the way through login_required.  The best practice is not obvious to me.

Comment: Why not have the user login before it can view the form?

Comment: This [S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62049176/django-form-content-lost-when-redirecting-using-login-required) might be useful.

Comment: may be  prevent default post behaviour? pop up a login modal, login using ajax and continue with the same form?

Comment: @Vincent Because we want to show people what is possible without the friction of a user account. No one wants to create an account when they don't know why to do it. So our interface is open until they do something that requires an account.

Comment: @FrédéricPerron I think this is probably the answer. Save the POST data in a session before logging in. I think I'd have to write a new `@my_login_required` decorator to accomplish that, but I think it's the only way.