# How to specify the name of the form variable used in the template of a FormView? (object_context_name for forms)

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

```
from forms import MyContactForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView 

class MyFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_forms.html'                                      
    form_class = MyContactForm  
    success_url = '/thanks/'
```

In my template, the form is called like this:

`{{ form }}`

But how can I call it like this:

`{{ my_contact_form }}`?

This would be the forms equivalent of `object_context_name`(for models).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907388/updating-context-data-in-formview-form-valid-method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could override `get_context_data`:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_forms.html'                                      
    form_class = MyContactForm  
    success_url = '/thanks/' 

    # from ContextMixin via FormMixin    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(MyFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        data['my_contact_form'] = data.get('form')

        return data
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do when you want to use multiple forms? I just thought passing each of them them to a data key and just dropping `form_class`. But I get a `TypeError, NoneType is not callable` when I do that.

Comment: You can only submit one form. `generic.edit.FormView` manages one form. Look at the [source of FormMixin and ProcessFormView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py): you'll have to override `get` and `form_invalid` to render all the forms and you'll have to override `post` to determine what form was submitted and process it. At this point, I don't think you should inherit from `FormView`.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276398/multiple-form-classes-in-django-generic-class-views, especially the second update to the accepted answer.